# What is the JBoss equivalent of Tomcat's server.xml?

Tags: java, configuration, tomcat, jboss, connector

I am running an application which was deployed on JBoss.

There is only documentation for Tomcat, none for JBoss.

I need to change some connector tag attributes to look like so:

```
<Connector className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector"
port="8443" minProcessors="5" maxProcessors="75"
enableLookups="true"
acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
useURIValidationHack="false" disableUploadTimeout="true">
</Connector>
```

Where can I find the file equivalent to server.xml in JBoss?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default jboss configuration (Jboss version 4.2.x) file setup is well described here: [Server Configuration File Set](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/config-files.html) JBoss uses Tomcat as web engine, this intended to be configured directly so it is deployed un-packed as a folder (`server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat50.sar`) rather than a JAR file. You can configure this Tomcat deployment as you would any other.

Comment: since jboss 5 the server.xml has been under server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/

Comment: thanks, good to know the last version of jboss I used was 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

In jboss-4.2.2.GA I found it at :
server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/